# Is there a way to use std::fill() using function return value, and the function needs an input equals to container index?

Tags: c++, stl

i.e.

```
int ToBeFilled[10];
int GenerateSomething(int x);
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) ToBeFilled[i] = GenerateSomething(i);
```

How to do it using std::fill()?

```
std::fill(ToBeFilled, ToBeFilled + sizeof(ToBeFilled), GenerateSomething(/*How to do?*/));
```

////
Update:

The `GenerateSomething(i)` is actually a function call returning a pointer, like `pObj->GetIt(i)`.
Normally I just need one specific pointer so I will use it like `pObj->GetIt(0)`, but in some cases I need to get all of them, so that a loop emerges.

Comment: Curious, why do you need the index? Are you mapping from one container to another?

Comment: I'll edit my post for more information. Actually it's a function call of an object, and it returns a pointer. Say it's like `pObj->Get(i)`, but I'm getting for all `i`'s

Comment: The loop is probably cleaner than any functional alternative, though Boost.Range may simplify it a bit.

Answer (score 4):

Yet another, slightly different (and C++11 only) approach:

```
using std::begin;
using std::end;

std::iota(begin(toBeFilled), end(toBeFilled), 0);

std::transform(begin(toBeFilled), end(toBeFilled), 
               begin(toBeFilled), GenerateSomething);
```

If you're working with a lot of data, this could be problematic (it's rather cache-unfriendly), but with a container as small as you're dealing with, this isn't an issue at all.

Edit: of course, if you want to avoid that, you could just write an iota that takes a functor (like they probably should have included in the standard):

First a little header I'll call "numericx":

```
#ifndef NUMERICX_H_INC_
#define NUMERICX_H_INC_
namespace stdx { 
template <class FwdIter, class T, class Func>
void iota(FwdIter b, FwdIter e, T start_val, Func f) { 
    while (b != e)
        *b++ = f(start_val++);
}
}
#endif
```

[Note that for non-trivial iterator and/or T, it might be better to replace the post-increments with pre-increments in separate statements].

Then the (now-trivial) code that uses it:

```
#include "numericx"

stdx::iota(begin(toBeFilled), end(toBeFilled), 0, GenerateSomething);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
struct Filler {
    int real_;
    int &index_;
    Filler() : real_(0), index_(real_) {}

    int operator()() {
        return GenerateSomething(index_++);
    }
};

std::generate(ToBeFilled, ToBeFilled + 10, Filler());
```

Edited due to Mark B's comments. Tested with a version of `generate` (written by me) which *does* make a copy of the function object for each iteration:

```
template <typename It, typename F>
void generate(It start, It finish, F func)
{
   for(;start != finish;++start)
   {
      F generator = func;
      *start = generator();
   }
}
```

Comment: Oh, this works so elegantly too. The sad part is that I've seen this before.

Comment: It's sad this didn't come to mind at all. The description is literally "I need a function that stores state." A functor is a perfect match.

Comment: If you have C++11 there is `std::iota` for this.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Unfortunately, `std::iota` won't do the job by itself -- it only assigns consecutive values, not the result of executing a function on the value. It can still be part of a solution though (I used it in my answer).

Comment: This solution stores the state locally in the functor, so there are potential issues with the state being incorrectly maintained if copies are made.

Comment: @MarkB Wouldn't the default copy constructor take care of maintaining state?

Comment: @anthony-arnold: not necessarily. It could, for example, copy the original parameter to a temporary at each iteration, then invoke that temporary. Each invocation when then pass `0` as the parameter to `GenerateSomething`.

Comment: @MarkB OK, what about this: `Filler` holds two members, `int real_` and `int &index_`. Initialiser list looks like this: `real_(0), index_(real_)`. That way, a copy of the Filler always has `index_` referring to the original `real_`. Would that fix it? Adds an extra member to copy, but should work around the problem.

Comment: @chris: Technically its not a _functor_ but a _function object_, though both are frequently used _(incorrectly)_ to refer to the same thing.

Comment: @K-ballo: What is the difference? The first reference that I checked said that they are the same. [A Function Object, or Functor (the two terms are synonymous)](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/functors.html)

Comment: @anthony-arnold That should do the trick. The usual way however is to store the state outside the function object and store just a reference to it. `int current_val = 0; std::generate(ToBeFilled, ToBeFilled + 10, Filler(current_val));`

Comment: @MarkB I thought of that too. I guess that would be more efficient (although it might not be a stretch for the compiler to optimise the unused counts away.) I think it's a better way; but my way is slicker in terms of readability. That being said, I'd probably use your way if performance is critical.